# GET request works on backend with Postman, but returns null to frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose

I have a GET request where if I add the creator to the post as a param like api/watchlist/?creator=5dac9d3567aca81e40bfc0 and test it in Postman, the results return all posts by that creator with the following code correctly.

app.js

```
  app.get('/api/watchlist',(req, res, next)=>{
  Watching.find({ creator: req.query.creator})
  .then(documents => {
    console.log("Creator value: " + req.query.creator);
   res.status(200).json({
     message: 'User\'s watchlist items retrieved!',
     posts: documents

  });

   });
   });
```

If I try and pull the GET request into angular, then it returns nothing.
Also the front end when I open the relevant webpage says frontend is saying `ERROR TypeError: "retrievedData.posts is undefined"
    getWatchListItems watch-list.service.ts:72`

watch-list.service.ts

getWatchListItems(creator: string) {

```
this.http
  .get<{ message: string; posts: any; maxPosts: number; watchlist: string }>(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/watchlist?creator=" + creator
  )
  .pipe(
    map(retrievedData  => {
      console.log(retrievedData.watchlist);
               return {
        posts: retrievedData.posts.map(post => {
      console.log(retrievedData.watchlist);
          return {
        title: post.title,
        cost: post.cost,
        listingOwner: post.listingOwner,
        id: post._id
          };

        }),
        maxPosts: retrievedData .maxPosts
      };
    })
  )
  .subscribe(transformedPostData => {
    console.log(transformedPostData);
    this.posts = transformedPostData.posts;
    this.postsUpdated.next({
      listing: [...this.posts],
      postCount: transformedPostData.maxPosts
    });
  });
```

}

watching.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = localStorage.getItem("userId: ");
    //  this.userId = this.authService.getUserId();
    this.watchListService.getWatchListItems(this.userId);
    this.postsSub = this.watchListService
      .getPostUpdateListener()
      .subscribe((postData: { listing: Watching[]; postCount: number }) => {

        this.totalPosts = postData.postCount;
        this.posts = postData.listing;

      });

  }
```

Comment: just after your line : ```map(retrievedData => {``` add, ```tap(console.log)```, and show what you get

Comment: I got tap working added, but it doesn't output. The only thing that is outputting is " the frontend is saying ERROR TypeError: "retrievedData.posts is undefined"
    getWatchListItems watch-list.service.ts:72

Comment: from your api response, it looks like this line: posts: `retrievedData.posts.map` should become `posts: retrievedData.watchlist.map`. Your api doesnt return `posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the create as a route parameter in angular service.

So you need to modify your api like this:

```
app.get('/api/watchlist/:creater', (req, res, next) => {
  Watching.find({ creator: req.params.creator })
    .then(documents => {
      console.log("Creator value: ", req.params.creator);
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'User\'s watchlist items retrieved!',
        watchlist: documents
      });
    });
});
```

And if you dont want to change the api, you should send the creator as a query param like this:

```
return this.http
      .get<{ message: string; posts: any; maxPosts: number }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/watchlist?creator=" + creator
      )
```

After this, you must handle the response data in angular, and transform to your needs.

Can you update the question, by including this console.log result with this code?  (as I know in the service you don't need to subscribe,  you are subscribing in your component)

```
getWatchListItems(creator: string) {

  return this.http("http://localhost:3000/api/watchlist?creator=" + creator)
    .pipe(
      map(retrievedData => {
        console.log("retrievedData: ", retrievedData);
        //todo: transform retrievedData

        return retrievedData;
      })
    )
}
```

Don't forget your api returns the data in this format, so you should

```
{
  "watchlist": ...
   "message": ...
}
```

Comment: I updated my code to reflect your answer, but it's still returning "retrievedData.posts is undefined" on the frontend console so it's still returning nothing.

Comment: @user6680 what does  console.log(transformedPostData); output? can you add to your question? And also  can you add a console.log to here: .pipe(
        map(retrievedData => {  console.log("data: ", retrieveData); ...

Comment: console.log("data: ", retrievedData) returns data[object Object]

Comment: @user6680  And what about console.log(retrievedData.watchlist)? In the place in my answer

Comment: I updated my code at the top to show up to date. I added console.log(retrievedData.watchlist) in two places in the code at the top if you check. But I never see it appear in console.

Comment: I just changed watchlist: documents to posts: documents because of what you said and it returned the correct number of posts, but the data on site says undefined. so it's closer now and doesn't say retrievedData.posts is undefined, but not returning the data

Comment: You just need to convert the response you get from your api

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!